# MVC routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to setup routing as follows:

/Profile/Edit -> routes to Edit action

/Profile/Add -> routes to Add action

/Profile/username -> routes to Index action with parameter username, because action username doesn't exist.

So I want the second parameter to be parsed as the controller action, except when no controller with that name exists; then it should route to the default index page and use the url part as id.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt's solution gets you 90% of the way.  However, instead of using a route constraint to exclude action names, use a route constraint to include only valid usernames, like so:

```
public class MustMatchUserName : IRouteConstraint 
{ 

    private Users _db = new UserEntities(); 

    public MustMatchUserName() 
    { } 

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) 
    { 
        return _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == values[parameterName].ToString().ToLower()) != null; 
    } 
}
```

Then, as Matt points out, in the user creation process, you must enforce a rule that your ActionNames are not valid for user names.

counsellorben

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex in your route constraints like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserProfileRoute",
    "Profile/{username}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" },
    new { username = "(?i)(?!edit$|add$)(.*)" });
```

this will match urls like `/profile/addendum` `/profile/someusername` and will ignore `/profile/edit` and `/profile/add`

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible. However, why not just make /profile your root?

If that isn't possible, you may need to hardcode your action's routes.

Comment: Hmmm yeah, kind of stupid but I didn't really think of that :) I just might, that would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

Make these your routes in Global.asax.cs:

```
 routes.MapRoute("UserProfileRoute", "Profile/{username}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" });
 routes.MapRoute("DefaultProfileRoute", "Profile/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "SomeDefaultAction" });
```

This will match /Profile/someUsername as expected. But it will fail for all other actions. All action names are assumed to be usernames now. A quick fix to this is to add an IRouteConstraint to the first route:

```
 routes.MapRoute("UserProfileRoute", "Profile/{username}", 
     new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }, 
     new { username = new NotAnActionRouteConstraint() });
 routes.MapRoute("DefaultProfileRoute", "Profile/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "SomeDefaultAction" });

 public class NotAnActionRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint 
 {
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string value = values[parameterName].ToString();

                    // it is likely parameterName is not cased correctly,
                    // something that would need to be 
                    // addressed in a real implementation
        return typeof(ProfileController).GetMethod(parameterName,
                         BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null;
    }
 }
```

However, this is a bit ugly. Hopefully someone knows of a better solution.

You also have problems when one of your users picks a name that is the same as an action :)

Comment: Yeah, I though about that last comment and I'm going to implement some reflection logic to prevent users from choosing a username which equals an action.

Comment: By the way, Facebook does the same these times, I can open my Facebook profile via facebook.com/username. Not so dangarous for my name, but others might be trickier. I wonder what they'll do if they ever want to create a folder or whatever at an address a user has already claimed.